# Warnings: Cross-plaftorm Xamarin Blank App (Xamarin.Form portable)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.   HelloWorld.Droid        1   Active


    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'HelloWorld, Version=, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'HelloWorld.dll'
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String fullName, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String fullName)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.GetAssembly(String fileName)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract(ICollection`1 jars, ICollection`1 resolvedResourceDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedAssetDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedEnvironments)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() HelloWorld.Droid
```

I have got the same problem as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40197362/warnings-creating-cross-plaftorm-xamarin-blank-app-xamarin-form-portable-in-v). But there wasn't a solution to it.

I have tried updating xamarin, reinstalling visual studio with xamarin, installed almost every android sdk and tools but the error stays. I have even made a new solution but the same error appears.

[image: References]

Update:

With advice from the awnser of the question dev_man metioned I deleted all api's except the api 23 and above. After that is tried to update the nuget packages he mentioned but from version 23.0 to 25.1.0 . This failed and I got this error:

```
     Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    ErrorCould not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 25.1.0'. 
You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.
 For more information, contact the package author.
```

Comment: Can you show what references are included in your project?

Answer (score 1):

Well there are a number of problems that can lead to the surfacing of this issue and sadly the core issue doesnt seem visible at the initial stage. 
This previous question covers a wide range of the possible causes if one reads thoroughly the solution may be found. your error might change as you follow the various steps.
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40935404/debug-emulator-getting-started-with-android-using-xamarin)